# Show selected item name instead of selected Id in Angular 11

Tags: angular, angular8, angular9, angular11

When I select a value from select dropDown I can only print ID but I wanted to show **Description** instead of **Id**. I just want to show the Name but I want to send that selected value Id to API.

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cz8cG.png)

**component.ts**

```
pay = [];

paymentForm = new FormGroup({
   paymentType: new FormControl('', []),
   description: new FormControl('', []),
   amount: new FormControl('', []),
});

btnAddToPayment(payment: SalePayment) {
  this.cartService.addToPaymentCart(payment);
  this.pay.push(this.paymentForm.get('paymentType').value);
}
```

**Html For Select**

```
    <select formControlName="paymentType" class="mb-3 form-control" id="Payment">
          <option value="" disabled selected>Payment type</option>
          <option *ngFor="let pay of selectPayment" [value]="pay.Id">
            {{pay.Description}}
          </option>
     </select>
```

**Html for btnAddToPayment**

```
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <span class="btn btn-default input-group-text" (click)="btnAddToPayment(paymentForm.value)">
                      <i class="fa fa-plus-square" style="color: green"></i>
                    </span>
          </div>
```

**Table**

```
 <tr *ngFor="let paym of payment">
          <!--              <td>{{paym.paymentType.Description}}</td>-->
          <td>{{paym.paymentType}}</td>
          <td>{{paym.amount | currency:'RS: '}}</td>
          <td>{{currentDate | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}</td>
 </tr>
```

**Interface**

```
export class SalePayment {
  SaleId: string;
  PaymentTypeId: number;
  Description: string;
  Amount: number;
  Balance: number;
}
```

2. I want to push selected values to the array and save them to DB. There may be multiple payments.

Answer (score 0):

As per your select dropdown, you're setting the value field to save as payment Type

- This approach is correct

Use like this to display name | description as td element

```
<td>
  <span *ngFor="let pay of selectPayment" [hidden]="pay?.Id !== paym?.paymentType" >
     {{pay?.name}}
  </span>
</td>
```

Comment: can u explain where I need to put this code.?

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

```
 <tr *ngFor="let paym of payment">
          <!--<td>{{paym.paymentType.Description}}</td>-->
          <td>
            <span *ngFor="let pay of selectPayment" [hidden]="pay?.Id !== paym?.paymentType" >
               {{pay?.name}}
            </span>
          </td>
          <td>{{paym.amount | currency:'RS: '}}</td>
          <td>{{currentDate | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}</td>
 </tr>
```

Comment: It's giving empty space

Comment: do you have the `name` field in `selectPayment` array. or else `Description` use this field

<span *ngFor="let pay of selectPayment" [hidden]="pay?.Id !== paym?.paymentType" >
               {{pay?.Description}}
            </span>

Answer (score 0):

You can use find to filter out the object with required Description.
Something like this (I'm assuming that you are populating the payment Array with the form values. If not so, let me know)

```
btnAddToPayment(payment: SalePayment) {
  this.cartService.addToPaymentCart(payment);
   const selectedObj = selectPayment.find((item:any)=>{
      item.Id === payment.paymentType
   });
   if(selectedObj) {
     payment['paymentName'] = selectedObj.Description;
   }
  this.pay.push(this.paymentForm.get('paymentType').value);
}
```

In HTML,

```
<tr *ngFor="let paym of payment">
          <td>{{paym.paymentName}}</td>
          <td>{{paym.amount | currency:'RS: '}}</td>
          <td>{{currentDate | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}</td>
 </tr>
```

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to get values from the form array. I tried you suggestion and I got below error in this line.

  **item.Id === payment.paymentType**

Below is the error

**Property 'paymentType' does not exist on type 'SalePayment'. Did you mean 'PaymentTypeId'?**

Comment: Can you share the SalePayment interface?
I thought `btnAddToPayment(payment: SalePayment) {`  
will have the formValue, that is why I used the paymentType as on the paymentForm

Comment: I added my Interface.

Comment: What I'm curious about is btnAddToPayment receives the form value. So it should contain paymentType. Is there any other method where you are mapping this formValue to SalePayment?  Can you do a console.log(payment) in btnAddToPayment and then

Comment: I tried explaing in here
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kylv5c?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts